# Нужно ли тут тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Когда мы указываем какой-то промежуток времени, например, "апрель-май" или "год-полтора", то, понятно, что между этими словами ставится дефис. Но как быть, если временные рамки записаны словосочетаниями? Например, "конец апреля (—) начало мая". По идее, тут тоже должен стоять какой-то знак. Я ставлю тире, но всегда сомневаюсь.
Как правильно записывать такие временные рамки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В этом вопросе (с временными промежутками) есть маленькая тонкость у Розенталя:

> §82. Соединительное тире
>
> 1. Тире ставится между двумя или несколькими словами для обозначения пределов:
>
> а) пространственных, например: поезд Москва – Иркутск – Хабаровск – Владивосток;
>
> б) временных, например: Крестовые походы 11–13 веков; **массовые отпуска в июле – августе,**
>
> в) количественных, например: рукопись объемом восемь – десять авторских листов (то же цифрами: 8–10); 5–6-кратное превосходство.
>
> В этих случаях тире заменяет по смыслу слова «от... до». **Если же между двумя рядом стоящими числительными можно по смыслу вставить союз или, то они соединяются дефисом, например: уехал на два-три дня (но при цифровом обозначении ставится тире: 2–3 дня).**

Сравните: *запланировал отпуск на апрель-май* (апрель или май); *экспедиция на Таймыр состоялась в апреле — мае 1955* (т. е. в течение двух  месяцев).
*Конец апреля — начало мая*. Безусловно, здесь должно стоять тире. Сочетания слов не могут соединяться с помощью дефиса.

Comment: Кстати, длинное тире не обязательно делать из двух коротких. Красивее будет, если набрать Alt+151: —